# Empty body in POST in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

Basically, I am sending a POST request with an empty data body:

```
  ASIHTTPRequest *request [ASIHTTPRequest alloc] init];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString]];
  [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
  [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];
  [request startSynchronous];
```

But i am getting this response each time:

Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSStringEncodingASCII. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.

I am wondering if it's mandatory to set post values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have much experience with the ASIHTTPRequest wrapper but I can see you are initialising it with `alloc:init` whilst most examples I've seen have a convenience initialiser `requestWithURL:(NSURL*)url` i.e.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [AIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:escapedUrlString];
```

At a guess I'd say this convenience initaliser will also set some of the required variables for your post request to work, including `NSStringEnconding`.

From the ASIHTTPRequest documentation at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_text_encodings

> Handling text encodings
>
> ASIHTTPRequest will attempt to read
>   the text encoding of the received data
>   from the Content-Type header. If it
>   finds a text encoding, it will set
>   responseEncoding to the appropriate
>   NSStringEncoding. If it does not find
>   a text encoding in the header, it will
>   use the value of
>   defaultResponseEncoding (this defaults
>   to NSISOLatin1StringEncoding).
>
> When you call [request
>   responseString], ASIHTTPRequest will
>   attempt to create a string from the
>   data it received, using
>   responseEncoding as the source
>   encoding.

Comment: Just to confirm after quickly reviewing the code, this is in fact the case. Check the interface file (ASIHTTPRequest.h) for details on init/dealloc methods.

Answer (score 3):

As Rog says, use initWithURL or requestWithURL. Anyway, in my case the problem was that I was connecting to a slow server and the request timed out giving the "Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected" error.

I solved it with:

```
request.timeOutSeconds = 50;
```

You can try with more than 50 second if your server is even slower.